# How do I call a variable from a void method in another class

Tags: java, class, constructor

How do I call the string variable user, from a void method in another class

I constantly get an error running this code because user in the getUser() function doesn't equal user in the action(ActionEvent j) function.

Class Alpha:

```
public class Alpha(){

private string user;

public Alpha(int temp){
temp = 0;
}

public void action(ActionEvent e){
String command = e.getActionCommand();
user = "hi";
}

public String getUser(){
return this.user;
}
```

Main:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Alpha n = new Alpha();
    String username = n.getUser();
    System.out.println(username);

}

}
```

Comment: user remains null because you never assign it an object.

Comment: Are you attempting to set the value of `user` in the `action` method? If so, change it to be `this.user = "hi";`.

Comment: What do you mean by I never assigned it an object

Comment: You're assigning a local variable instead of the class field.

Comment: Sorry I just made the edit to how it's supposed to be

Comment: This is the original problem

Comment: It doesn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where are you calling the action() method?

Comment: Call the action method to set the value of user so that it has a value when the getUser method is called.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, because the constructor of `Alpha` expects an int parameter, but you don't provide one. `action` is never called in your example. What do you expect `n.getUser()` in your example to return? And what error are you referring to?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the action(ActionEvent j) method?

Comment: what the point of temp?

Comment: This is just a short example of my complete code, temp is for something else. But I think I figured it out, however, when I include action() in my getUser() method, it's requesting a parameter for the ActionEvent

Comment: Nevermind, got it

Answer (score 0):

Here a summarry of all the problems :

Class Alpha:

```
public class Alpha(){

private string user;

public Alpha(int temp){ why do you need a temp argument?
temp = 0; //why do you set temp at 0?
}

public void action(ActionEvent j){ // why do you need an ActionEvent j argument?
user = "hi";
}

public String getUser(){
return this.user;
}
```

Main:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Alpha n = new Alpha(); //you call a contructor but not the one you write -> Alpha(int temp)
    String username = n.getUser();
/** you try to get the username here but it was never set (so it = null)
    you set it in action(ActionEvent j), so you can try to insert
    action(j);
**/
    System.out.println(username);

}

}
```

Comment: sorry its ActionEvent e and it's too include a method called getActionCommand(). I didn't include all of my code because its too long

Comment: It is hard to understand without all the code. you sould provide a working exemple at least. But for what I understand this may sould you problem : public void action(ActionEvent e){
this.user = "hi";
}